# WPF multiline RadMaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Does anybody know how to make RadMaskedTextBox multiline  in WPF? I use Telerik Q1 2011.

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox MaskType="None" Name="textBox" 
                              MaskedText="some text"
                              Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="1" >

    </telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check, the following link [Telerik Support](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/maskedtextbox/how-to-add-multiline-on-maskedtextbox.aspx), it targets Silverlight but I suppose you can use the same approach in your case

Comment: Thanks for help, i had seen this link but i cant modify the default template becouse there is no full example.

Comment: Do you know your way around Templates etc in general? Do you know where to start?

Comment: You can find the complete template here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/maskedtextbox/not-wrrapping-radmaskedtextbox.aspx